# Count Days using Dense Row function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table which contains data for all the action performed on a particular object. The table below appears something as follows:

```
ActionId ProductName   ProductPart        ActionDate             ActionStatusId
   1        Bike          abc123     3/24/2013 12:00:00 -4:00          7
   2        Bike          abc123     3/25/2013 12:00:00 -4:00          3
   3        Bike          abc123     3/25/2013 15:00:00 -4:00          1
   4        Bike          abc123     3/26/2013 16:00:00 -4:00          3
   5        Bike          abc123     3/26/2013 16:00:00 -4:00          3
   6        Bike          abc123     4/26/2013 15:00:00 -4:00          3
   7        Bicycle       def432     4/27/2013 12:00:00 -4:00          1
   8        Bicycle       def432     4/26/2013 12:00:00 -4:00          4
   9        Bicycle       def432     4/27/2013 12:00:00 -4:00          3
   10       Bicycle       def432     4/28/2013 12:00:00 -4:00          1
```

Now i need to get productname, productpart, laststatusid (only if it is 3 or 1), [No of days since statusid = 3]

So basically if last statusid based on last actiondate is not 3 or 1 i don't need that data, which i am able to get using row_number function.

But after that i need to count no.of days if statusid = 3. I don't need to count days if the last actionstatusid = 1.

But i have a problem in achieving it, because if the **last statusid = 3** then i need to **count no.of days not from that instance but the instance when it went to that status till date.**

So, for **productname Bike** i should be getting following result:

```
ProductName ProductPart  ActionStatusId  [No. of Days Since Statusid = 3]
   Bike        abc123           3                34 (i.e. getdate() - 3/26/2013) as it went to statusid = 3 since 3/26/2013 and not taking just last actiondate
   Bicycle     dec432           1                 -
```

I tried using row_number,dense_rank function but able to achieve it. Is there a way to achieve it?
Also, i am working with sql 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
        ActionId INT
      , ProductName VARCHAR(50)
      , ProductPart VARCHAR(50)
      , ActionDate DATETIME
      , ActionStatusId TINYINT
)

INSERT INTO @temp (ActionId, ProductName, ProductPart, ActionDate, ActionStatusId)
VALUES 
    (1,  'Bike',    'abc123', '20130324 12:00:00', 7),
    (2,  'Bike',    'abc123', '20130325 12:00:00', 3),
    (3,  'Bike',    'abc123', '20130325 15:00:00', 1),
    (4,  'Bike',    'abc123', '20130326 16:00:00', 3),
    (5,  'Bike',    'abc123', '20130326 16:00:00', 3),
    (6,  'Bike',    'abc123', '20130426 15:00:00', 3),
    (7,  'Bicycle', 'def432', '20130427 12:00:00', 1),
    (8,  'Bicycle', 'def432', '20130426 12:00:00', 4),
    (9,  'Bicycle', 'def432', '20130427 12:00:00', 3),
    (10, 'Bicycle', 'def432', '20130428 12:00:00', 1)

DECLARE @Date DATE = GETDATE()  

SELECT 
      ProductName
    , ProductPart
    , ActionStatusId
    , CASE WHEN ActionStatusId = 3 
        THEN MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, ActionDate, @Date)) 
        ELSE 0
      END
FROM @temp
WHERE ActionStatusId IN (1, 3)
GROUP BY 
      ProductName
    , ProductPart
    , ActionStatusId
```

Output:

```
ProductName   ProductPart  ActionStatusId Count
------------- ------------ -------------- -----------
Bicycle       def432       1              0
Bicycle       def432       3              2
Bike          abc123       1              0
Bike          abc123       3              35
```